# In AngularJs, how value propagate from real view value --> $viewValue --> $modelValue --> real model value and vice versa?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I don't know how to ask this question. this question always confusing me,when i write a custom directive. to understand better this question , i take an example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
```

while typing in text box, on each change, a handler function execute. this handler call `ctrl.$setViewValue(value)` ,where ctrl is `ngModelController` and `value` is real value(which i have typed in text box).thus real view value propagate to $viewValue. till here all concept is cleared.but i don't know how $viewValue propagate to $modelValue and to real model value and vice versa. please recommend me some tutorial for this or please share your knowledge here :)

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did the answer below address your question? If so, consider accepting as answer

Comment: @New Dev , I got the concept using your answer, and i also search web to go more deeply. and i found many resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, `$modelValue` is the value the `ngModel` directive is bound to - i.e. the model. For example, `name` below:

```
<input ng-model="name">
```

The `$viewValue` is the value shown in the DOM - i.e. the View.
Each input control has its own meaning of what it means. For example, for the `<input>` element, the `$viewValue` is:

```
element.val()
```

but for a custom input control it could be whatever and however you define it.

`ngModel` provides hooks for directives that `require: "ngModel"` it to transform and validate the value. In addition, `ngModelOptions` allows to delay the commit of the value to the model after a possible delay

```
model -->                      $formatters --> $validators --> view
view  --> (debounce delay) --> $parsers    --> $validators --> model
```